# How would i refactor this angular 2 observable to not duplicate on route change

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have this working fine for me at the moment if the page remains static as below.

Using a service to get results of a http call on a timer to repeat

```
this.lts.getEventDetails(link,currentTime)
  .subscribe(res=>{
    this.rs.setCurrentRace(activeRound['uid'],res.S);
  })
```

Which calls this function in my service

```
getEventDetails(liveTimingLink:string,time:number){

  let link  = `${liveTimingLink}?R=${time}`
  let timer = 5000;

  Observable
    .interval(timer)
    .flatMap(() => {
      return this.http.get(link)
        .map(res=>{return res.json()})
    })
}
```

The problem is it just duplicates the timer observable every time i route change and come back.

I'm not sure how i should tackle this, i was thinking i would set the observable to a variable in the service and just return it but i do not know how i would do this.

Or should i do it like i am doing it but just unsubscribe as the route changes? Again i don't know how to exactly do this.

Any advice ideas is very welcome. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of creating the observable outside the method call is good.

**BUT... Every `.subscribe()` an observable receives invokes a NEW execution of the observable.**

It means it's not enough to have one instance of the observable. You also need to *share the execution* among all subscribers.

Initially, I thought you could use the [.share()](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-share) operator, but it will only share the observable **as long as it has at least one subscriber**. It wouldn't work in your case since the observable loses its only subscriber when the user leaves page. The next time the user visits the page, the observable needs to re-execute from scratch (in other words, the interval resets). I suspect this is not what you want.

I found a solution that uses the [.publish()](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-publish) operator to share the observable, and `.connect()` to make it start emitting values the first time it's retrieved. The interval keeps running whether you're subscribed to it or not.

Check out this [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/MJKVNTzba3K0BGmvj07G) to see it in action. The subscribe/unsubscribe buttons replicate what happens when the user navigates to/away from the page. Open up the browser console to view the values received by the subscriber.

Code for the service:

```ts
@Injectable()
class MyService {
  // Create the interval once and share it among all subscribers.
  source = Observable.interval(1000).publish();
  intervalStarted = false;

  getEventDetails(param) {
    // The first time the observable is retrieved,
    // connect to it (= make it start emitting values).
    if (!this.intervalStarted) {
      this.source.connect();
      this.intervalStarted = true;
    }

    // Here, continue transforming the original observable using operators like mergeMap().
    return this.source.map(val => `${val} - ${param}`);
  }
}
```

A few minor notes about your version of the `getEventDetails()` method:

- You could drop the `{ }` around the bodies of your arrow functions. That way you'd get an implicit `return` and your code would be more compact. You might want to keep your version for readability, though.
- If you're using Angular2+, you're using RxJS 5 and the "official" operator is `mergeMap()`. `flatMap()` comes from RxJS 4 and is just an alias for `mergeMap()`.
- Since the local variables in the method don't change, you can declare them with `const` vs `let`.
- Why is there no `return` in front of `Observable.interval`?

Here's the rewritten method:

```ts
getEventDetails(liveTimingLink:string, time:number){

  const link  = `${liveTimingLink}?R=${time}`;
  const timer = 5000;

  return Observable
    .interval(timer)
    .flatMap(() => this.http.get(link).map(res => res.json()))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came back to this and appreciate your thoughts on the issue and the advice,  i always appreciate feedback from a more experienced coder.

I ended up re-working the code to simply unsubscribe from the observable on route change. Seemed simpler and took care of my needs

Service:

```
getEventDetails(liveTimingLink:string,time:number){

  const link  = `${liveTimingLink}?R=${time}`
  const timer = 5000;

  return Observable
    .interval(timer)
    .flatMap(() => {
      return this.http.get(link)
        .map(res=>{return res.json()})
    })
  }
```

Component:

```
saveLiveRaceString(serie:FirebaseObjectObservable<any>,activeRound){

  /**
    Only map & subscribe if current event has begun.
  **/

  const currentUnix = moment().unix();

  if(currentUnix > activeRound['mainEventUnix'] ){

    this.eventSubscription = this.lts.getEventDetails(serie['liveTimingLink'],currentUnix)
      .subscribe(res=>{
        this.rs.setCurrentRace(activeRound['uid'],res.S);
      })
  }

}

ngOnDestroy() { 

  /**
    Unsubscribe from the event observable
  **/

  this.eventSubscription?this.eventSubscription.unsubscribe():null
}
```